# Read configuration from xml resource with nested elements

Tags: android

I have this xml resource:

```
<resource>
    <Mail name="mail1">
        <Host>gmail</Host>
        <Port>123</Port>
    </Mail>
    <Mail name="mail2">
        <Host>hotmail</Host>
        <Port>321</Port>
    </Mail>
<resource>
```

i would like know how can i get all the values of the resource's nested nodes
thanks for the help.
Niv

Comment: Have you tried to do Google first? There are plenty of resources for "XML Parsing" available.

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+xml+parsing

Answer (score 2):

Use DOM Parser or SAX Parser .
u can find a good Description of both [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/)

for more help search on google for DOM and SAX parsing